# Angular 11 directive how to dynamically change colour code reading from scss variable

Tags: sass, angular11

I have the following drag-drop directive created in Angular 11. On drag a file over i have different color and on dragleave different color. I dont want to hardcode the colour code instead read from the scss file i.e for eg: colours.scss. Can anyone help how to do this?

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Output, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDragDropFileUpload]'
})

export class DragDropFileUploadDirective {

    @Output() fileDropped = new EventEmitter<any>();
  
    @HostBinding('style.background-color') private background = '#ffffff';
  
    // Dragover Event
    @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) dragOver(event): void {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.background = '#e2eefd';
    }
  
    // Dragleave Event
    @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public dragLeave(event): void {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.background = '#ffffff';
    }
  
    // Drop Event
    @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public drop(event): void {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.background = '#ffffff';
      const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
      if (files.length > 0) {
        this.fileDropped.emit(files);
      }
    }
  
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by adding a class name based on boolean getter in the angular directive.

```
setBackgroundColor = false;

@HostBinding('class.highlight-drop') get backgroundColor() {
  return this.setBackgroundColor;
}

// Dragover Event
@HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) dragOver(event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.setBackgroundColor = true;
  //this.background = '#e2eefd';
}

// Dragleave Event
@HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public dragLeave(event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.setBackgroundColor = false
}
```